# No containers created when database is leveldb in hyperledger fabric2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

when we run **./network.sh up -s couch-db** there will be couch-db instances(containers) for every peer but when we deploy network with level-db as database why there are no containers for that?
the network file is in fabric-samples/test-network.
[conatainers when database is level-db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQP33.png)

[containers when database is couch-db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCzPl.png)

Answer (score 0):

When the Peers are started up using the default configuration, i.e. using the LevelDB database as State Database, no additional containers to the peers are started up. The LeveldDB database is executed within the Peer, i.e. it is an embedded process, as you can read [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_as_state_database.html)